# When using Views slideshow with videos I cannot get the slideshow to stop in order to play the full video

Tags: views, files

I have created a slideshow with images and videos using [Views Slideshow](https://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow).
 I slide through the content of a content type that has images and embedded youtube videos (using the youtube module).

I have one image or one video per content and it works fine. The only problem appears when I try to play a video. The slideshow passes to the next slide whilst the video is still playing.

Do I need to change the cycle options (within the slideshow options) in the view? or do I need custom code?

I have already tried many things within the slideshow options but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Short answer is you need custom code.

Comment: Have you lookup http://wearepropeople.com/blog/how-to-create-slideshows-with-embedded-youtube-videos-in-drupal-7 ?

Comment: Thanks. It seems complex. I am just going to create a block with views and have the videos and images separate. i.e. a slideshow with images and a block with a couple of videos (and a pager to go from one to the other).